# How can I set a variable in Batch after an "if exists" check?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

How can I set a variable in Batch after an "if exists" check?

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist ('dir c* /B /A:-D') set Lo=C
echo Lo: !Lo!
pause
```

I expect the results to say "Lo: C" rather than currently just "Lo:" when I have a file starting with C in the folder.

Comment: `If` command CANNOT accept the command as a data source. See `IF /?`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to directly process the output of another cmd is using [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

```
@ECHO OFF
if exist "X:\Path\c*" (set "Lo=C") else (set "LO=n/a")
echo Lo: %Lo%
pause
```

To asure it's not a directory

```
@ECHO OFF
Set "LO=n/a"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D "X:\Path\C*" 2^>NUL') Do set "Lo=C"
echo Lo: %Lo%
pause
```